# Dividing a shape into congruent subregions

Tags: algorithm, shapes, geometric-arc

Given an irregular many face polygon with equal sides. Is there any algorithm to divide it into six equal sized congruent regions ??

Comment: I don't think this is always possible.

Comment: don't think this is possible except in special cases.

Comment: i know its not always possible. but i am trying to find out whether some special pattern in the input if present can ensure presence of this.

Comment: You could detect `D3` or `C6` symmetry, but they are subject to floating point issues and they are not neccessary. If the shape tiles the plane, it should be possible to subdivide as well.

Answer (score 5):

No. Such subdivision is not always possible:

Consider the polygon `P` obtained by joining two regular polygons `P1` and `P2` with a different and very large number of sides `N1` and `N2`. This polygon approximates a pair of circular disks `C1` and `C2` to within an arbitrary precision.

Consider a subdivision thereof into six congruent regions.

Consider the set of vertices of `P1`. There must be a region that contains at least `(N1)/6` vertices. Call the vertices `V1` and the region `R1`. There must be a region that contains at least `(N2)/6` vertices of `P2`. Call the vertices `V2` the region `R2`.

If `R1 != R2`, then there must be a congruence mapping `R2` to `R1`. If `2*N1 < N2`, such mapping is impossible. Choose N2 to be much larger than N1.

Thus, `R1 == R2`. There is a region that contains both `V1` and `V2`. The diameter of each region must be larger than the diameter of `P2`.

Use the two-circle approximation. Each region must contain an arc of at least 1/6 of the perimeter of `C1` and an arc of at least 1/6 of the perimeter of `C2`. Also, there is at least one region that is inside both circles and no region is entirely inside the smaller circle.

Consider the possible congruences of `R1`. Any congruence either 1) is the reflection along the main axis or 2) maps either P1 or P2 outside P or 3) maps some part of the perimeter to the interior of P. The reflection is not sufficient, so any subdivision must contain a congruence that maps some part of P1 to the interior of P1.

Thus, each region boundary must contain a concave arc with the diameter of `12`. Intuitively, this shows such subdivision cannot exist.

---

There are many classes of polygons that you could detect:

- Order-6 rotation symmetry `C6`. These can be subdivided in any way that respects the rotation symmetry.
- Order-3 dihedral symmetry `D6` (order-3 rotation + mirrors). Cut along the mirrors.
- shapes that tile the plane with translation with four polygons meeting at a vertex. These are the shapes that have two pairs of matching opposite paths. Duplicate the cutting edge in one direction and triplicate in the other.
- some shapes have a reflection symmetry and each individual half has an order-3 rotation symmetry. These can be detected and cut as well.
- some shapes have an order-2 rotation symmetry and can be cut in two congruent regions that have an order-3 rotation symmetry. Look for a repeated pattern along the boundary.
- some shapes have an order-3 rotation symmetry and can be split in three regions with a symmetry. I'm not sure I could reliably detect such shapes (detecting `C3` is easy, subsequent cutting isn't) and I'm a human.
- ...
- polyominoes are shapes made out of squares, polyhexes are shapes made out of hexagons and polyiamonds are shapes made out of triangles. They are easy to detect and *some* even have a subdivision. The subdivision, if exists, may be difficult to detect as well, but *at least* you can enumerate all subdivisions that respect an aligned grid at the correct size to see if they are congruent.
- ...

To demonstrate the complexity of the problem: There is a certain class of logical puzzles where the goal is to split a complex shape (60 squares) in two congruent regions. If it is *not easy* for a *human* to split a *polyomino* in *two* congruent regions, how do you expect a *computer* to split a *general shape* in *six* congruent regions?

If you *do* want to detect the most cases where the subdivision is possible, you have to trade off between programming time (to support more and more special cases) and test strength. For starters, stick with `C6, D3 and checkerboard tiles => easy to subdivide; polyforms => maybe possible; the rest => probably no subdivision`.

Comment: Very nice analysis. but there are cases when such division is possible. from a given region how can i identify whether such division is possible ?? and if it is then how can i do it ?